# How to add colour in ruby text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
select[name="invoice[budget_line_id]"]
  - BudgetLine.all.each do |budget_line|
    |  <option value="
    = budget_line.id
    | ">
      Balance:
    = budget_line.budget_balance
    - if budget_line.budget_balance>=@invoice.total_amount
      = budget_line.description
    - else
      = budget_line.description
      = '[ Insufficient budget balance]'
```

I want to add red color on else part '= budget_line.budget_balance' =
'[ Insufficient budget balance]'.
How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to style HTML? If so, it’s not a Ruby question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `html.haml` file - i.e. this is a templating system to generate HTML.

Text colour in HTML is set with [the `color` style](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp). Here is a most basic implementation:

```
- else
  = budget_line.description
  %span{style: "color:red;"}= '[ Insufficient budget balance]'
```

However, it is usually considered best practice to set styles in CSS rather than inline like this. You could give this `<span>` a class name, and apply the red colour to that class.

You can see an interactive example using CSS [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Colors/tryit.asp?filename=trycolors_currentcolor).

Comment: Hi. Thank you. This may take to the close. I have a SCSS file.

select {
  color: green;
  width: 100%;
  option.color-1{
    color: red;
  }
}

what will be the code for add this red color to else part?

Comment: @RiazRahmanAranya I could not advise using vaguely-named CSS classes like "color-1", but... That code is saying to apply the `red` colour style to any `color-1` **CLASS** inside any `<option>`. In other words, if you use `%span{class: 'color-1'}`, or (if it's actually suitable to use a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`), use `.color-1`, then this colour will be applied within that container.